# How can I address a specific element of a bytea in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I need to make a query based on a specific element of a `bytea` column in PostgreSQL. I tried the following query:

```
select * from my_table where bytea_column[4] between 160 and 183 limit 1
```

-but it gives me `ERROR: cannot subscript type bytea because it is not an array`.

Is there a way I can select a specific element of a `bytea`? I would like to avoid casting it to `text` and using `like %%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `get_byte` function. This allows you to retrieve a single byte.

Alternatively you can use the `substring` function to retrieve a sequence of bytes.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html